# error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'IplImage *' (or there is no acceptable conversion) OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, cascade-classifier, eye-detection

Hi I am trying to use this code [Cascade Classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html). I got the error in title. I am using VS 2013 and OpenCV 3.0.

I am new and I don't understand why this code works for everybody except me?
What is the way to fix it?

Here error line:

```
frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
```

Comment: I edited back to the original question. Let's see your new one :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cvQueryFrame` returns an `IplImage*`, while your `frame` is of type `Mat`.

You have two options:

1) Convert from `IplImage*` to `Mat`

```
frame = Mat(cvQueryFrame(capture));
```

2) use C++ syntax, with [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture) (**recommended**)

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
...
for(;;)
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you but another problem was occured. I edited my question

Comment: @ffttyy Another problem means another question. Don't modify the original question so that the answers are no longer valid. If this answer solved your original problem, mark as an answer, and open a new question with the new problem.